# iOS: Core data schema for follow system

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

I have a follow system in mysql and php that uses just one table as follows:

Following

id|userid|followerid

(There is also a users table: id|username|pass)

Whenever a user follows another user, an entry is made with the followerid in the follow column and the person being followed in the userid column.

I am now trying to access this from an iOS app using a web service.

For the VC, I would like to be able to list the users but by means of chaingng the NSPredicate toggle between the followers of the user and the people the user is following.  This is trivial using php/sql but am having deuce of a time translating to CoreData.

Right now I have users Entity in core data with following attributes:

id|username|pass

And copying the mysql schema, I also have a Following entity 
fid|fuserid|ffolowerid

In turn, I have created a one to many relationship for user to followers and an inverse one to many relationship for user to following as a given user (such as the user of the app) can have many followers and also follow many people.

The web service is currently set to provide users and for each user a set of follower ids along the following lines
id:1
name:bob
followerids: 2,3,4

At this point I am stumped.  I can populate the users entity.  I can also populate the followers entity with all the people following the user and all the people the user is following.

However, I don't know to communicate to Core data which followers are related to which user and also I don't know how to write a predicate that, for example, just pulls the followers of the user of the App.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Right now my NSManagedObjects look like the following:

```
   //User.h
    #import "Following.h"
    @class Following;

    @interface User : NSManagedObject
    //in user entity
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * uid;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * uname;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *upass;

    //this is relationship
    @property (nonatomic, retain) Following *following;

    @end

//and Following.h   
     #import "User.h"
    @class User;

    @interface Following : NSManagedObject

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * fid;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * fuserid;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * followerid;
    //this is relationship
    @property (nonatomic) User *user;

    @end
```

After importing and saving users from web service, I try to save some information about followers in Following entity but not sure what I am doing here....

```
 NSSet*followerids = importUser.followerids;
                    NSInteger *folnum =[followerids count];
                    if (folnum>0) {
                    for (id item in followerids) {
                        Following *newFollowing = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Following" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
                        newFollowing.fuserid = useridnum;
                         NSNumber *itemnum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[item intValue]];
                        newFollowing.followerid = itemnum;
                        newFollowing.user = record;  //where record is a user just created     
                    }
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear which users and relationships you are trying to store. Are you trying to store ALL users and relationships that exist in your backend system in Core Data? Or only the relationships for the user of the app?

Comment: A fair number of users say 20 or so recommended users so that the app user has a chance to follow them.  But as far as follow relationships, only users the app user is currently following or users currently following the app user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You effectively have a many-many relationship (each `User` can follow many other `Users`, and can be followed by many `Users`).  You could model this directly in CoreData, without creating an additional entity, by having *two* to-many relationships, `followedByUsers` and `usersBeingFollowed`, with one being the inverse of the other.  The resulting model would look like this:

[image: DataModel]

Your `User` class definition would then look something like this:

```
@interface User : NSManagedObject
//in user entity
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *uid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *uname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *upass;

//this is relationship
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *followedByUsers;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *usersBeingFollowed;

@end
```

If your web service is providing a `userid`, `name`, and a set of `followerids`, I would first create all the `Users`, without setting any relationships, then loop through and establish the relationships by fetching the `User` records corresponding to the `followerids`:

```
NSPredicate *userPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid == %@",importUser.userid];
NSFetchRequest *fetchUser = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
fetchUser.predicate = userPredicate;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchUser error:nil];
User *record = results[0];
NSSet *followerids = importUser.followerids;
NSInteger folnum =[followerids count];
if (folnum>0) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid IN %@",followerids];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
    fetch.predicate = predicate;
    NSArray *resultsArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
    if ([results count] > 0) {
        NSSet *followers = [NSSet setWithArray:resultsArray];
        record.followedByUsers = followers;
    }
}
```

(For simplicity I've omitted the usual error checking.)  Having built the relationships, you can determine which users follow a given user with:

```
givenUser.followedByUsers
```

Or if you want to use a predicate (eg. for a fetchedResultsController), use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"usersBeingFollowed CONTAINS %@",givenUser];
```

Conversely, to get the Users that `givenUser` is following, use

```
givenUser.usersBeingFollowed
```

or

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"followedByUsers CONTAINS %@",givenUser];
```

Comment: I take it the first four statements are to get right record.  Right now I am doing this immediately after creating and saving the record as follows:  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            // Initialize Record
            NSManagedObject *record = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

Comment: However, even though I added the followedByUsers property in User.h, it is giving me error 'Property followedByUsers not found on object of type NSManagedObject

Comment: @zztop Change to `User *record = [[User alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];`, so it knows that `record` is the `User` subclass of  `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: Ok.  I am now setting the record ok.  When I log it out record.followedByUsers it shows:Relationship 'followedByUsers' on managed object (0x1558e6e0) <User: 0x1558e6e0> (entity: User; id: 0x1564c530 <x-coredata://89522CE2-36AC-47AD-AC3F-68FFC3B58944/User/p17> ; data: {
    followedByUsers =     (
        "..."
    );
    following =     (
    );
    uid = 5;
    uname = test;
    usersBeingFollowed =     (
    );
    }) with objects {(
    <User: ...> ; data: {
    followedByUsers =     (
    );
    following =     (
    );
    uid = 4;
    usersBeingFollowed =     (
        "..>"
    );
})
)}

Comment: so not sure if that is something I can work with or not.

Comment: @zztop I think that looks as it should.  You've created one User object with one `followedByUser`.  You can get an array with all the `followedByUsers` with `[record.followedByUsers allObjects]`.

Comment: Using FRC to fetch imported users that are followers of app user, how would I write predicate ?  From answer: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"usersBeingFollowed CONTAINS %@",givenUser];  How do I indicate givenUser?  Each user is uniquely identified by user.uid; and I keep track of app user with NSuserdefault userid

Comment: You could add the `uid` to the predicate: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY usersBeingFollowed.uid == %@",userid];`.

Comment: Awesome it worked. Thanks many!  To someone with dbase background, it still seems a bit parsimonious to do everything from one entity, users, but I still learning.   Do you think this is the way to go for production app?

Comment: @zztop I think it should be OK for production - there's a very similar example in the CoreData documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW1) (see Many-to-Many relationships).  If you're anxious about the parsimony, you could follow the alternative approach outlined in the following section (Modeling a Relationship Based on Its Semantics), which adds another entity similar to your `Following` table.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the relationship here then. Based on your explanation there should be many to many relationship here.

So your User class should have a property like

```
//this is relationship
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *following;
```

And your Following class should have a property like

```
@property (nonatomic) NSSet *users;
```

Then you can start assigning the Set of follower ids to that you  are receiving from the webservice to it.